# Moving table row to another table and getting it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code below that allows me to move the values from `Random Fruits Table` to the `Green Fruits Table` the problem is i would like to try to make it so that after i move that value i want to be able to get that value back from the `Green Fruits Table` by the same way which is clicking on the row but i don't want the original values from `Green Table` to be clickable or affected is there any easy way to accomplish this? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated thank you.

```js
var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

var key = "Red Fruits";
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry'];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado'];
var myArray2 = [];
myArray2.push(obj);

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

function redraw(obj) {

  var $header = $("<tr>"),
    cols = 0,
    bodyString = "";

  $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, values.length);
    $header.append($('<th/>').text(key + ": " + values.length));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    bodyString += '<tr>';
    $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
      bodyString += '<td>' +
        (values[i] ? values[i] : "") +
        '</td>';
    });
    bodyString += '</tr>';
  }
  $('.fruitsclass thead').html($header);
  $('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
  var bodyString = '';
var headString = '';
$.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td></tr>');
});
headString += ('<tr><th>' + 'Random Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
$('.fruityclass tbody').html(bodyString);
$('.fruityclass thead').html(headString);
}


function listener(obj) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fruityid td").click(function() {
      getval(this);
      data = this.innerHTML;
      k1 = Object.keys(obj2).find(k => obj2[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
      index = obj2[k1].indexOf(data);
      obj2[k1].splice(index, 1);
      obj[key2].push(data);
      redraw(obj);
      listener(obj);
    });
  });
}

function getval(cel) {
 // alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
redraw(obj)
listener(obj);
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
}

table {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

th {
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />

  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="result"> </div>
    <div class="center">
      <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <table id="fruityid" class="fruityclass skillsTable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call redraw everytime for adding a single row to the table.

You need to do like below to be able to identify the newly added fruits from green fruit table,

Here's the fiddle that works like you asked [jsFiddle](https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/aKwoQP)

```js
 var obj = {};
var obj2 = {};

var key = "Red Fruits";
obj[key] = ['Apple', 'Cherry', 'Strawberry'];
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(obj);

var key2 = "Green Fruits";
obj[key2] = ['Watermelon', 'Durian', 'Avacado'];
var myArray2 = [];
myArray2.push(obj);

var key3 = "Random Fruits";
obj2[key3] = ['Kiwi', 'Pomegranate', 'Honeydew', 'Plum'];
var myArray3 = [];
myArray3.push(obj2);

function redraw(obj) {

  var $header = $("<tr>"),
    cols = 0,
    bodyString = "";

  $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
    cols = Math.max(cols, values.length);
    $header.append($('<th class="total_count_'+key.replace(/\s/g,'_')+'"/>').text(key + ": " + values.length));
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    bodyString += '<tr>';
    $.each(obj, function(key, values) {
      bodyString += '<td>' +
        (values[i] ? values[i] : "") +
        '</td>';
    });
    bodyString += '</tr>';
  }
  $('.fruitsclass thead').html($header);
  $('.fruitsclass tbody').html(bodyString);
  var bodyString = '';
var headString = '';
$.each(obj2[key3], function(index) {
  bodyString += ('<tr><td>' + obj2[key3][index] + '</td></tr>');
});
headString += ('<tr><th>' + 'Random Fruits' + '</th></tr>');
$('.fruityclass tbody').html(bodyString);
$('.fruityclass thead').html(headString);
}


function addNewRow(fruitName) {
  var tds = '<tr><td class="new-row">' + + '</td></tr>';
}

function listener(obj) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fruityid td").click(function() {
      getval(this);
      data = this.innerHTML;
      k1 = Object.keys(obj2).find(k => obj2[k].indexOf(data) >= 0)
      index = obj2[k1].indexOf(data);
      obj2[k1].splice(index, 1);
      obj[key2].push(data);
      $(".total_count_Green_Fruits").html(key2 + ': ' + obj[key2].length);
      var element = $(this).detach();
      $('#fruitsid > tbody').append('<tr><td></td><td class="new-green-fruit">'+element.html()+'</td></tr>'); //since we need to add to green fruit
      // now, if you want 
    });
  });
}


$('body').on('click', '.new-green-fruit', function() {
   alert("clicked on new green fruit : " + $(this).html());
});


function getval(cel) {
 // alert(cel.innerHTML);
}
redraw(obj);
listener(obj);
```

```css
.class {
  font-family: Open Sans;
}

.center {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center
}

.skillsTable th {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
}

table {
  float: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 70%
}

td {
  border-left: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  border-right: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 11px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

th {
  color: #0080ff;
  font-weight: normal;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #AAA5A4;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"> </div>
    <div class="center">
      <table id="fruitsid" class="fruitsclass skillsTable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <table id="fruityid" class="fruityclass skillsTable class">
        <thead></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

What I've done is, detach the td from the random fruit table and attach it to the green fruit table with a class "new-green-fruit", this helps to differentiate newly added tds vs the old ones.

Also, I've registered a click event for new-green-fruit tds alone, so you get an alert only when clicking on those new fruits

Comment: but by doing you method my array for `Green Fuits` will not get the data from the `Random Fruits` Table

Comment: Yeah but the counter beside the `Green Fruits` Header doesn't increase. Because the way i did it is that the value from `Random Fruits` will move into the array of `Green Fruit`

Comment: Updated answer, check now

Comment: Ahh thanks it works now but why doesnt the value counter work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not sorting after the fruit are moved to green fruit, so the original fruits of green fruit must be having the original index in the green fruit array. You can create a function to move the green fruit to random by clicking(which you have done before), with checking the index of the fruit(index>=3)